# Retrieving XY from point graphics set in WPF network (arcgis 10.0)

Tags: arcgis-10.0, coordinates, network, wpf

I  have a WPF application using ArcGIS 10. In the application I can set two point by clicking on map and calculate route between them. every time I click on the map, The application creates a GraphicsLayer and a Graphic element using this code:

```
GraphicsLayer stopsGraphicsLayer = myMap.Layers["myStops"] as GraphicsLayer;
Graphic stop = new Graphic() [Geometry = e.MapPoint };
```

My question:

I need to get the XY Coordinates of the points clicked on the maps. Does anybody know what elements\attributes\methods to get this information?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer (I've been looking for it a week):
the coordinates are part of the geometry attribute.

The code I added to get the coordinates of the stop is this:

```
ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Geometry.Geometry whats = stop.Geometry;
```

This returns a type saying somthing like "Point[x=456543.34,y=456234.23,WKID=2045]"

and if I want to do anything with it, I can record it as a string, split it as I want and parse it to an int.

Thanks again.